# Downvote Correct (Although not "Good") Answers?

Tags: discussion, voting

I see questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940984/syntax-error-in-nested-if#) fairly often. I voted to close (closed now) but the question still gets some answers and a lot times these answers get a bunch of votes. While they are correct they are not "good" answers, at least according to my understanding of good answers. A "good" answer shouldn't only be correct but it should at least have a small amount of usefulness to future users. SO is not a linting service so pointing out small typos and missing colons and the like is not what we are here for.

Aside from down voting which in the case of these answers wouldn't have done much what should be done?

There was also a point where I got in to an argument with a higher rep rep user at some point the past (I've tried finding it but I can't seem to find it) after down voting an answer of theirs like this. Their point was that their answer was correct and therefore it shouldn't be down voted. They asked me to point out a help center link that said to not answer bad or off topic questions. Both of the users in the linked question should have known this would be closed (one of them could have even voted to close it).

So what should be done in this instance? These users should have flagged/voted to close but instead they pointed out a typo and were somehow rewarded with a pretty good amount of upvotes.

EDIT: I guess a better question is "Are answers pointing out typos 'good' answers?" While they are technically correct they are not especially "good." I don't believe they add anything of value to the site.

Comment: If you don't feel it's a good answer, downvote.  I'm not sure why this would be a meta-question.  I see your line of reasoning, but clearly others feel otherwise -- hence the voting system.

Answer (score 8):

You should be voting on posts based on whether or not they are *useful*.  That is specifically what the voting tooltip states.

It's absolutely possible for an answer to be correct, but not useful.  It could have information that's correct, but not relevant to the question, it could be missing key information even if what information it does have is correct, it could be unclear or not present the information it has in a way that allows the readers to understand it, even if it's technically correct, etc.

If you feel that the post isn't useful then you should *absolutely* be downvoting it.

Comment: I'm interpreting the op's question as whether the answer is "meta-useful", that is, useful to the site's ongoing quality and health.  Answers to bad questions encourage those types of questions, which is not useful to the site.  Whether "meta-useful" answers should be downvoted (consensus elsewhere seems to be no) is what's in question.

Comment: @davidism You're trying to group different criteria, or classes of criteria, for a post being useful.  SE's policy isn't that certain types of usefulness are to be considered and certain types aren't.  Users are given wide latitude to use whatever criteria they feel is most appropriate when evaluating the usefulness of posts.  If you wish to not consider future readers when evaluating "usefulness", that's your decision.  If someone else does, that is also fine.  That other people choose to use a certain set of criteria in no way means you, or the OP here, needs to.

Comment: If Ian feels that this post isn't useful because nobody else is going to have this problem, or because if they are, they'd never find that post to get their solution, then he's more than welcome to provide that feedback by voting.  If you feel that the post is useful despite the fact that there will never be a single person that will read the post and be glad that they read it for the rest of time, I certainly can't stop you.  I don't know what would make you think it would be useful, but if you really think it's useful, then you can provide that feedback.

Comment: I agree with you, just pointing out that they were discussing a particular kind of usefulness, which wasn't directly addressed.